# last-child element from class

Tags: jquery, html, css

given this html

```
    <div class="my_div">a</div>
    <div class="my_div">b</div>
    <div class="my_div">c</div> 
    <div>other</div>
```

I want select all `.my_div` element, but not last element from this class, this works not correct

```
            $(".my_div:not(:last-child)").css({
                color: "#090"
            });
```

how can select all element from some class, except last element?

Comment: could you rename the last element to something different besides `.my_div`? If not, would a `for` loop work? I'm sorry, I'm not very good with jquery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:last-child` is exactly that, the **last child**, not the last child of a given tag.

jQuery offers the [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), which does what you want, but has the cost of being something jQuery does rather than something the browser does. Thus:

```
$("div.my_div:not(:last)").css({
    color: "#090"
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ewowax/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ewowax/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
$(".my_div").each(function(ind,el){
 if(el == $(".my_div:last")[0]) return true;//continue;
 $(el).css({color: "#090"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mys3k/1/

Comment: Try it. You'll find that it doesn't do what the OP says they want to do.

Comment: @ Travis: If you're going to use custom jQuery selectors, *really* use them. See my answer for how. But this does, at least, actually work (or it looks like it might), as opposed to the earlier version. :-)

Answer (score -1):

maybe simliest if you use css classes with jQuery for this problem:

```
// add .nostlasts class to all .my_div divs
$('.my_div').addClass('notlasts');
// remove .nostlasts class from last .my_div
$( $('.my_div')[ $('.my_div').length ] ).removeClass('notlasts');
```